# how to reload the chat Message/listing of chat automatically in applozic framework

Tags: ios, swift, applozic

how to reload the chat Message/listing of chat automatically in applozic framework. in the demo of the Applozic gives refresh button to reload chat message and listing of chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done the notification setup correct  it will reload the chat listing automatically

You can check this in push notification test tool, if the setup is correct or not  you will get **success**  response in status column

[Push notification test tool link](https://www.applozic.com/docs/push-notification-test.html)

This is doc link for ios  push notification setup   [link](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/ios-push-notification)